# What template is loaded by Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I was following Django tutorial, and got stuck where it asked me to replace the default template for administrative part of the site with my own.  The problem was a typo in the template's name.  I suspected there must be a problem like that, but to troubleshoot the problem it'd be very helpful to see some kind of report from Django on what template it used to render a particular page.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that would be in the error message. What exactly do you need apart from that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman there wasn't an error message: Django used the default template failing to find the one I intended for it to use.

Answer (score 5):

- First if you have set `DEBUG = True` django automatically gives you information about where django was looking for templates (in general and especially in case it didn't find one)

You should see something like this:
[image]

- second you can add the popular django plugin **django-debug-toolbar**. It can show you for each request what templates were used and what their context was.

see: https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/panels.html#template

[image]

Comment: I have `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`, but Django just renders the page, it doesn't show the debug information. Though your answer gives me an idea: say, raising an error in the view, for which the wrong template was rendered would give me this page, I could then find the information I need. Though I hoped that I could, for example, configure testing server to print which files have been served or something along those lines.

Comment: I could also install the debug toolbar, but I'd still prefer a solution that doesn't require additional code (the toolbar needs to get its information somewhere, doesn't it?)

Comment: Please see the screen I added to my answer, django out-of-the-box is very debug-friendly. It may be that there is a problem with your config. Though I'm not sure what you mean by 'just renders the page'. Not finding the specified template already is an exception.

Comment: There are two templates: one comes with `django.contrib.admin` and another one "monkey-patched" in the project directory. The point of [the tutorial I'm reading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/) is to illustrate monkey-patching. However, if I make a mistake in monkey-patched template's name, I will not get an error: Django will simply load the original template. Thus there will be no error. You screenshot is of the debug panel, I was talking about not using this panel.

Answer (score 2):

Still, not exactly the answer, but something to get me closer. One could start Django shell, and then try this:

```
>>> from django.template.loader import get_template
>>> get_template('template/name').origin.name
```

to find out what template was actually used.  This is still not enough to see though which templates were considered while resolving the template.